# How to set title of TriggerEditDialog Managed Wrapper

Tags: window, task, scheduler

I am using class TriggerEditDialog of task scheduler managed wrapper to create/edit triggers. The title of this dialog is always set to "New Trigger". In edit mode I would like to set it to "Edit Trigger", before displaying it,i,e, before calling ShowDialog().How can I set it?.

```
TriggerEditDialog triggerDlg = new TriggerEditDialog(trigger, false);
triggerDlg.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve in following way.

```
TriggerEditDialog triggerDlg = new TriggerEditDialog(trigger, false) { Text = "Edit Trigger" };
triggerDlg.ShowDialog();
```